# How to specify which database to query from the BaseX console?

Tags: database, xpath, command-line-interface, xquery, basex

How do I switch between databases?  Or, more specifically, if multiple databases are open, how would I specify which database to run a query against?

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ basex
[warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/jing.jar in /usr/share/java
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> LIST
Name     Resources  Size   Input Path                       
----------------------------------------------------------
books99  1          61253  /home/thufir/basex/db.books.xml  
foo      1          61253  /home/thufir/basex/db.books.xml  
new      1          61253  /home/thufir/basex/db.books.xml  

3 database(s).
> 
> OPEN foo
Database 'foo' was opened in 72.11 ms.
> 
> OPEN new
Database 'new' was opened in 16.43 ms.
> 
> CLOSE foo
Stopped at , 1/6:
Syntax: CLOSE 
  Close current database.

Closes the currently opened database.
> 
> CLOSE
Database 'new' was closed.
> 
> exit
Enjoy life.
thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

Mostly I'm just running `XQUERY /` from the `BaseX` console at the moment, establishing the existence of data.

Comment: Something like [`db:open`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:open)?

Comment: Yes.  That would be part of an `XQuery` file?

Comment: Perhaps something like `XQUERY db:open("foo")/xpath/to/the/where/you/want`?

Comment: I'm more coming at it from **within** the console, or Java, like:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9637909/262852   but, yes, that's the idea.  I would think that BaseX has a `LIST` operation and similar.  Or perhaps that's more through the console than `XQuery` stand-alone files?

Comment: I don't know about BaseX Java operations, but my previous comment should work for you in the `basex` application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a complet answer, but to run a query against a specific database open that database and run the query:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ basex
[warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/jing.jar in /usr/share/java
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> LIST
Name       Resources  Size   Input Path                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
books      1          61253  /home/thufir/basex/db.books.xml      
bookstore  1          6164   /home/thufir/basex/db.bookstore.xml  

2 database(s).
> 
> OPEN books
Database 'books' was opened in 67.74 ms.
> 
> XQUERY /bookstore/book/title

Query executed in 217.72 ms.
> 
> OPEN bookstore
Database 'bookstore' was opened in 2.2 ms.
> 
> XQUERY /bookstore/book/title
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
Query executed in 6.08 ms.
> 
> OPEN books
Database 'books' was opened in 2.48 ms.
> 
> XQUERY /bookstore/book/title

Query executed in 1.09 ms.
> 
> exit
Have a nice day.
thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

notably, never closed a database.  I suppose the context is whichever database was most recently opened?